# Avoiding a Slow Loop in R - dplyr Solution?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I've got a problem which I can solve with a slow and clumsy loop in R. However, I'm hoping there's a more elegant (and faster) solution...

The simplest explanation I can think of: each row of data describes an action on a switch. The rows are sorted by switch ID (switch 1, switch 2, etc.) and by the chronological order of the actions. Each switch can either be on or off at any point in time. The action can be "turn on", "turn off" or "leave alone". For each row I want to know the status of the switch (on or off) both before and after the action described by that row.

Each switch starts in the "off" position.

(the data I'm working with actually relates to insurance policy data, but this switch-based analogy works and is probably simpler to understand)

A reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(switch_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
                  counter = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                  action = c("on", "off", "on", "off", "on", "same", "same", "same", "on", "same", "same", "same", "off", "off", "off", "on", "off", "same", "on"))
```

I can get to where I want to be using a not-particularly-elegant loop:

```
df$status_before <- NA
df$status_after <- NA

for(i in 1:nrow(df)) 
{

  if(df$counter[i] == 1)
  {
    df$status_before[i] <- FALSE # switch always starts in the "off" position
  }
  else
  {
    df$status_before[i] <- df$status_after[i-1]
  }

  if(df$action[i] == "on") {
    df$status_after[i] <- TRUE
  }
  else if(df$action[i] == "off")
  {
    df$status_after[i] <- FALSE  
  }
  else # "same"
  {
    df$status_after[i] <- df$status_before[i] # leave everything alone
  }

}
```

...but obviously in R loops are best avoided because they run very slowly. Doesn't matter in this tiny data set of course, but the real data I'm working with has ~1M rows so it could be a problem.

Is there a "vectorised" solution to this, perhaps using `dplyr` type commands?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a data.table solution:

**Edit**: Need to operate by switch_id; as of data.table v.1.12.4, there is a native way to fill in missing values (`nafill`) used in this edit; added some comments

```r
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(switch_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
    counter = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
    action = c("on", "off", "on", "off", "on", "same", "same", "same", "on", "same", "same", "same", "off", "off", "off"))

# in "status_after", replace "same" by NA and set "off" and "on" to FALSE and TRUE
df[, status_after := as.logical(factor(action, labels=c(FALSE, TRUE, NA)))]

# fill in NA using last observation carried forward, by switch_id
df[, status_after := as.logical(nafill(+(status_after), type = "locf")), by = switch_id]

# status_before: shift status_after (default: lag one), by switch_id
df[, status_before := shift(status_after), by = switch_id]

# set first instance of status_before per switch_id to FALSE
df[, status_before := c(FALSE, status_before[-1]), by = switch_id]

# reorder columns
setcolorder(df, c(1:3, 5, 4))
df
#>     switch_id counter action status_before status_after
#>  1:         1       1     on         FALSE         TRUE
#>  2:         1       2    off          TRUE        FALSE
#>  3:         1       3     on         FALSE         TRUE
#>  4:         1       4    off          TRUE        FALSE
#>  5:         1       5     on         FALSE         TRUE
#>  6:         1       6   same          TRUE         TRUE
#>  7:         1       7   same          TRUE         TRUE
#>  8:         1       8   same          TRUE         TRUE
#>  9:         2       1     on         FALSE         TRUE
#> 10:         2       2   same          TRUE         TRUE
#> 11:         2       3   same          TRUE         TRUE
#> 12:         2       4   same          TRUE         TRUE
#> 13:         2       5    off          TRUE        FALSE
#> 14:         2       6    off         FALSE        FALSE
#> 15:         2       7    off         FALSE        FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. Just one thing: status_before should be FALSE on row 9 because we’ve moved from switch_id = 1 to switch_id = 2. Is there an easy way to make that happen ie to have status_before always set to FALSE for the first record for each switch_id? Do I just say something like df$status_before[df$counter == 1] <- FALSE ?

Comment: Fixed in the edit of the answer - I missed that, sorry.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I'm not too familiar with the data.table dialect but maybe I should spend some time learning a little.

Comment: When you are working with large data, you may come to appreciate the speed and memory-efficient manipulations possible with `data.table`. Here is an introduction into its functions: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html. But if you are more comfortable with the `tidyverse` way you have your options as well (or could look into `dtplyr`).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand when I look at your loop, you want in `status_before` a `TRUE`/ `FALSE` dependent of the action of the previous `counter` and in `status_after` a `TRUE`/ `FALSE`dependent on the action of the actual `counter`. Did I get that right? Not quite sure though what you want with the `same` actions...

To look at values from previous rows, you can use the `lag()` function from `dplyr` (and to look "ahead", use `lead()` instead). This code gives the same output as your loop does:

**EDITED:**

```
# change "same" to last value of action (if you don't want to change the actual action column, create a new one)
df <- df %>%
  group_by(switch_id) %>%
  mutate(action = ifelse(action == "same", NA, action)) %>% # mark "same" as NA
  fill(action) # make sure action is a character string!

# do the actual evaluation
df <- df %>%
  group_by(switch_id) %>%
  mutate(status_before = case_when(lag(action) == "on" ~ "TRUE",
                                   lag(action) == "off" ~ "FALSE"),
         status_after = case_when(action == "on" ~ "TRUE",
                                  action == "off" ~ "FALSE"), 
         status_before = replace(status_before, is.na(status_before), "FALSE"))
```

This should be correct now!

Comment: Thank you. I'll look at the code shortly. To answer your question: if the action is "same" then I'd like status_after to be the same as status_before.

Comment: “same” could be viewed as “look at the switch but don’t touch it”

Comment: Thank you. That first chunk of code seems to work. However I'm struggling to understand the part of the code that says 

lag(action) == "same" ~ "TRUE"

Why would status_before always be TRUE in that case?

Comment: Maybe my example data set isn't quite covering all the possibilities, since "same" only appears in cases where status_before turns out to be TRUE. But it needn't always be like that. I've edited my original post to include a third switch_id where we have "same" where status_before is FALSE. In this case your code now gives different output to mine (status_before, row 19)

Comment: Oh I see - I changed my code. It should be ok now, but it's not as nice as @user12728748 data table solution (& also slower I assume).

Comment: Thank you. Still a lot quicker than my loop!

I'm much less familiar with the data.table dialect...a bit of future learning for me I think.